# Postgreql. How to select unique values and count it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column in postgresql

```
Names

Mike
Alex
Mike
Bill, Abigail
Abigail
Bill
Kurt, Adele, John
Mike
John
```

`,` is a delimiter when values two or more in the field.
How to to select it as result

```
Abigail 2
Adele 1
Alex 1
Bill 2
John 2
Kurt 1
Mike 3
```

I read about distinct and join but I can't make query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the values and then count:

```
select u.name, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     unnest(string_to_array(names, ', ')) u(name)
group by u.name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=301308098de07a91fc699e8d3412cd16) is a db<>fiddle.

Then you should fix your data model.  Do not store multiple values in a string column.  Postgres supports arrays which is one option.  Another is a proper junction/association table.

Comment: Why the cross join? Any advantage over `SELECT unnest(string_to_array(names, ', ')) AS name, count(*) FROM t GROUP BY 1`?

Comment: @fphilipe: Yours is just an implicit lateral join. The (one) advantage of Gordon's way is, that it better (in terms of more explicitly) conveys the logic behind it.

Comment: @stickybit, thanks, but is that so? Here's the [join explain](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0c395b5967875ca1e82161cddd64982) and the [explain for my suggestion](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=16c2932eac4a6bb4cbfc0069bb1f0239). I don't see any implicit join.

Comment: @fphilipe: Hmm, interesting, that surprises me indeed. Maybe I'm wrong? I'll try and look into this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, by `where` clause you mean the `group by 1`?

Comment: @fphilipe  . . . I meant in the `select` clause.  I'm opposed to functions in the `select` that multiple they number of rows.